# Check if byte array downloaded via SFTP is not corrupted

Tags: java, arrays, sftp, apache-commons

I have a java class for downloading voice recordings from SFTP server. I use Apache Commons API to do it. The steps should be:

1. download the recording to byte array (byte[])
2. validate if the downloaded recording is whole, correct and not corrupt in any way (I mean in comparison with the server one, if it is corrupted on a server then I don't care - I just need it to be the same)
3. delete the recording from the server

How can I do step 2 to be as sure as possible (maybe 100% is not possible I don't know)? So far I am just checking whether the byte[] is not empty but that is pretty weak. I looked at some checksums but I don't have any other access to the server than via SFTP in java application so I can't make the checksum on the server... Thank you for any help!

Comment: what is the sound format? (wav, mp3 etc.)

Comment: @Andrei : the sound format is always mp3

Comment: If you want to be really sure about the file integrity, there is a tool MP3Val  http://mp3val.sourceforge.net/ which can check the file. You can run it in command line using `Runtime.exec()` or read the sources and see how it's done, maybe you'll get some ideas.

Comment: SFTP is a binary protocol that runs over SSH which includes integrity checking. So the files *can not* be corrupted unless the SFTP client you use is buggy. If you have file corruption, you need to search for a bug rather than build corruption detection into your code.

Comment: what do you mean by SFTP client? The apache commons library that I use to connect to SFTP server? ... So you are saying that unless the library throws an exception, the download should be solid?

Comment: @Wolf That's correct. See also [How to check if Paramiko successfully uploaded a file to an SFTP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28967969/850848)

Comment: If anyone wants you can put that all in the answer and I will accept it so the next person that looks for it will know without reading comments. If nobody does that I will add the answer later and delete this comment.